# I want to know what is happening while executing this command?

Tags: bash

```
cd / | vi
```

This is the command that i have typed at the bash shell.
On executing this command , it just opens the vi editor. And then i have quitted using :q.
Now i am at the bash shell.
when we type any command here it wouldnot display ,but the command is executed.
I want to know where it is redirected.

Comment: Does entering the `reset` command fix the display? What about hitting `ctrl-l`? This sounds like your display is just still confused because of the awkward behaviour of `vi` in that running mode.

Comment: After hitting ctrl-l also not working.I have noticed that executed after  command cd / | vi are not notified in the history.

Comment: The commands execute correctly but do not end up in the shell history file if you exit the shell?

Comment: I'll let @Stephane-chazelas (or maybe someone else?) step-in with a marvelous explanation ;) but I guess: vi started in a non-terminal context (ie, instead of havign stdin="terminal input"(=keyboard), it had stdin="output of the command preceding the pipe". So it probably doesn't set "echo" back when it exits. see output of `stty -a` to see if "echo" is set. You can usually do `stty sane` to return to a sane state. See also http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stty for a definition of the different settings (for linux)

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow; I think it's a better fit for unix.stackexchange.com, as it concerns terminal behavior, not programming.

Comment: Similar kind of question is answered in http://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why

Answer (score 4):

Not 100% sure, but I would like to tell my opinion on that.

I think this has something to do with input/output control.

read man page of `cd`:

```
STDOUT
       If a non-empty directory name from CDPATH is used, or if cd − is 
used, an absolute pathname of the new working directory shall be written to the 
standard output
           as follows:

           "%s\n", <new directory>

       Otherwise, there shall be no output.
```

that is, if you `cd /`, the stdout is `/dev/null`, and pipe makes the stdout as stdin for vim.

When vim starts, it saves the terminal settings, input/output controls. But if it was `/dev/null`, not tty file descriptor, `vim` will not have the correct settings. And after you exit vim, it applis those in-correct things on your terminal.

To test, execute this:

```
cd -|vim
```

`cd -` will have stdout, then vim has normal stdin, after exiting vim, terminal should still work fine.

Then try this:

```
vim </dev/null
```

This does same as `cd /|vim`, after you exit vim, your terminal behaves strangely, as same as `cd /|vim`

```
stty sane
```

could rescue your terminal.